# Efficient way to identify the many points at which a large set of shapely LineStrings intersect?

Tags: python, intersection, shapely, numpy, geopandas

I have 10,000 shapely LineStrings in a geopandas GeoDataFrame. What is an efficient Python plus shapely (and/or optionally geopandas) way to produce a list of all the points at which these lines intersect one another?

```
import numpy as np, geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
n = 10000
x1s = np.random.random(n)
x2s = np.random.random(n)
x3s = np.random.random(n)
y1s = np.random.random(n)
y2s = np.random.random(n)
y3s = np.random.random(n)
lines = [LineString(((x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3))) for x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 in zip(x1s, y1s, x2s, y2s, x3s, y3s)]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=lines)
# now produce a list of points representing the many intersections of the LineStrings in gdf
```

Some similar questions on StackOverflow suggest ways to identify where LineStrings intersect Polygons or inefficient ways to split LineStrings, but none seem to answer this question.